# Is There a Whitepaper or Explanation of ECDSA somewhere?

Tags: encryption, key-exchange, ecc

Let's say I wanted to write an implementation of ECDSA from scratch to better understand it. I can't find a raw, non-abstract explanation anywhere. I tried tracking down the sources on the [wiki article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_Curve_Digital_Signature_Algorithm) and going through some posts and explanations on here, but I can't find anything of substance. Where do I find basic information on this?

Answer (score 2):

If you have access to IEEE Xplore or any other digital libraries that hold technical papers, I would say that is your best bet, as they usually explain concepts or implementations mathematically and algorithmically. If not, I found somebody's thesis online as a start, maybe he cites potential free resources  available in the bibliography.

http://www.nicolascourtois.com/bitcoin/thesis_Di_Wang.pdf

Comment: Thanks, I will check it out, unfortunately I don't have access to IEEE at the moment.